# How to generate a multi-line UILabel

Tags: objective-c, parsing, uilabel

I have a json call and I parse the results into a UILabel. In my json response I have a 4 Names under Clients.

I am trying to put all the Clients into my UILabel.

Currently I only see the last of the 4 clients from my json response but in my log I can see all 4 clients.

If you see the photo below you see brithouse which is the 4th client in the json call. I would like to view all 4 clients in mu uilabel? Currently I only see the last client.

Thanks

```
{
   "ProfileID":34,
   "ProfilePictureID":20,
   "Name":"Bilbo Baggins",
   "Clients":
   [
      {
         "ClientID":91,
         "Name":"Fnurky"
      },
      {  
         "ClientID":92,
         "Name":"A different client"
      },
      {
         "ClientID":95,
         "Name":"Second Community"
      },
      {
         "ClientID":96,
         "Name":"Britehouse"
      }
   ]
}
```

My objective C code

```
NSDictionary* json1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];


NSArray* latestLoans = [json1 objectForKey:@"Clients"]; //2

NSLog(@"Clients: %@", latestLoans); //3

NSArray *performersArray = [json1 objectForKey:@"Clients"];
for (NSDictionary *performerDic in performersArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [performerDic objectForKey:@"Name"]);

    jsonSummary.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The clients under this user are: %@ ",
                         [performerDic objectForKey:@"Name"]];
```

NSLOG

```
2013-05-16 13:03:52.820 com.barloworld.atajo[5137:907] Fnurky
2013-05-16 13:03:52.821 com.barloworld.atajo[5137:907] A different client
2013-05-16 13:03:52.821 com.barloworld.atajo[5137:907] Second Community
2013-05-16 13:03:52.822 com.barloworld.atajo[5137:907] Britehouse
```

[image]

Comment: Please remove the JSON stuff and restate your question:  You don't know how to generate a multi-line label.

Comment: you want all 4 names in one `UILable` or in 4 different `UILabels`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
            NSDictionary* json1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];
            NSArray* latestLoans = [json1 objectForKey:@"Clients"]; //2
            NSArray *performersArray = [json1 objectForKey:@"Clients"];
            NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
            for (NSDictionary *performerDic in performersArray) {
                [array addObject:[performerDic objectForKey:@"Name"]];
            }
            NSString *output=[array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
            jsonSummary.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The clients under this user are: %@ ",
                                output];
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use this..

**before the Loop:**

```
NSString *tempString = @"";
```

**In the Loop:**

```
tempString = [tempString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [performerDic objectForKey:@"Name"]];
```

**After the Loop:**

```
jsonSummary.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The clients under this user are: %@", tempString];
```

Answer (score 0):

This below of code will only add the **last value** into the `label`

```
jsonSummary.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The clients under this user are: %@ ",
                     [performerDic objectForKey:@"Name"]];
```

You have to APPEND each client name into string and then display the string value into the label... For appending into the string do,

```
JsonString =[NSString stringByAppendingFormat:   [performerDic objectForKey:@"Name"]];
```

Now this string will have all Client values, Now

```
  jsonSummary.text =[NSString stringWithFormat : @"YOUR OWN LINES %@ " JsonString];
```